# Find the tfs path of merged branch

Tags: api, tfs, merge, branch, tfs-sdk

Using TFS, I have trunk `$/project/trunk` and a branch `$/project/dev/feature/new_one`.

I have merged my branch back to trunk as follows:

```
C33($/project/trunk)
|  \
|   \
|    C32($/project/dev/feature/new_one)
|     |
|     |
|     |
...
```

I use the TFS API and can find the merge changeset C33. With the method `QueryMerges()`, I'm able to find the parent changeset C32 with all the changes on the files, but not the information I need :(

**Is there a way, using the TFS API, to find the repository path of the branch merged `$/project/dev/feature/new_one`?**

With the changeset C32, I'm only able to get paths of modified files, like `$/project/dev/feature/new_one/path/to/file.txt` but I'm unable to extract the path of the branch from the full path of the file :(

PS : A solution working since TFS2008 will be the best, but if it works only since 2010, it should be good...

PS2 : solving this problem will help to manage merge changesets in git-tfs which I develop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no API method to get a branch for a given item path, which you would think is a fairly common use case.

TFS 2010 onwards you can use [`VersionControlServer.QueryRootBranchObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.queryrootbranchobjects.aspx) to query all branches in version control. Using `RecursionType.Full` as the parameter to this method you will get a `BranchObject` array of all branches with no parent *and* all of their descendents. You can then determine a branch for a given file path as follows:

```cs
var collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsuri"));
var versionControl = collection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

var branchObjects = versionControl.QueryRootBranchObjects(RecursionType.Full);

var mergeFilePath = "$/project/dev/feature/new_one/path/to/file.txt";
var branch = branchObjects.SingleOrDefault(b => {
            var branchPath = b.Properties.RootItem.Item;
            return mergeFilePath.StartsWith(branchPath.EndsWith("/") ? branchPath : branchPath + "/");
        });

Console.WriteLine(branch.Properties.RootItem.Item);
```

As shown, the path to the branch is at `BranchObject.Properties.RootItem.Item`. I believe it is safe to find the relevant `BranchObject` in the array simply by checking which branch's path is contained in the merge file's path (given it is only possible match at most one branch as TFS enforces that only one branch can exist in a given folder hierarchy).

Just to be aware, I have been burned by [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772205/tfs-view-hierarchy-problem#details) Connect issue when using `QueryRootBranchObjects` in TFS 2012. The cause were some spurious branches that had apostrophes in the branch name.

The workaround to this is to use [`VersionControlServer.QueryBranchObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.querybranchobjects.aspx), however this takes an item identifier which is the exact path to the branch. Clearly you don't know the branch path at this point as all you have is a file path, so you have to recurse up the directories of the file path calling `QueryBranchObjects` each time until you get a match.

Comment: This solution is my fallback one but it doesn't please me for 2 reasons:
1. if your parent branch is not a branch but still a folder in tfs, you can get it with QueryRootBranchObjects() and can't find it
2. if you have multiple branches name dev, dev/test, dev/test2, dev/test3 and in your source code you've got a folder 'test' it could find that the good parent branch is 'dev' and in fact it was 'dev/test'. You can't 100% be sure :( Even if it's rare cases...

Comment: I've made an edit. 2. Is easy enough to solve, plus it is not possible to have a branch `$/dev` then another branch below it at `$/dev/test`. TFS does not allow this at the branching step.