# Find TFS items in other branches

Tags: tfs, merge, tfs-sdk

Here is a slightly different take on this question ([Find the tfs path of merged branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789639/find-the-tfs-path-of-merged-branch)), different enough to deserve its own question.

In the above link, the authors describe how you can programmatically traverse the folder hierarchy using TFS API to determine the parent branch object from a folder or item within a branch, and then you can get the branch information for that branch.

However, a different question is: how do you use TFS API obtain a path to a different branch of the original folder or item, taking into account that the item may have been renamed or moved in the other branch?

For instance: if I have an object $/MyProject/Main/Foo/bar.txt, I can easily figure out that the parent branch is $/MyProject/Main using the method described.  However, let's I also have the following versions of this file out there that were created by branching the original files:

```
$/MyProject/Dev/Foo/bar.txt
$/MyProject/Experiment/Foo/bar.renamed
$/MyOtherProject/Main/openbar.woohoo
```

How can I determine the list of references to the specific files or folders in a branch?  Clearly there is a way to do this because Visual Studio's merge dialog automatically populates the list of available targets with all references to the source file or folder, even if the source is not a branch.

Answer (score 0):

**If TFS has been used to move files or rename them**, as opposed to using the file system and then checking in 'new' files to TFS then you can use the history window to review the full history of a file, this will show you it's branch history and also any moves / renames that have occurred, this is because tfs uses an identifier for the file rather than its name.

Comment: While that is true, the purpose of this question is to ask how to do this programmatically using TFS API.  I will update the question to clarify.